# Why am I missing method CacheConfiguration.getMaxEntriesLocalHeap() after converting project to gradle project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I did 'right click on project > Configure > Convert to Gradle project' and after that I am getting an error:

```
The method getMaxEntriesLocalHeap() is undefined for the type CacheConfiguration    CacheService.java
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

When I download ehcache-core-2.6.0-source.jar the method is there.

Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Best regards,
mismas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in dependencies. I had 'ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar' pulled as transitive dependency of 'org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.1.9.Final'.
The solution was to exclude transitive dependency in projects build.gradle file like this:

```
configurations{
    all*.exclude group: 'net.sf.ehcache', module: 'ehcache-core'
}
```